# Estimote Android SDK Context

Tags: android, estimote

I am adding the Estimote SDK into an Android app. I am following Estimote's guide on GitHub available at https://github.com/Estimote/Android-SDK.

I am having trouble with this line of code and am getting an error that says "cannot resolve symbol 'context'".

```
private BeaconManager beaconManager = new BeaconManager(context);
```

Any ideas what I need to do to resolve that? It does not seem to be addressed in the Estimote guide.

Thank you!

Comment: That `context` is the root context of your app. If you have this code inside an `Activity` just change `context` for `this`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Android's [Context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) class. If you are inside an [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) then you can just call `getContext()` to obtain it.

See [SDK demos](https://github.com/Estimote/Android-SDK/tree/master/Demos) how to do it. In particular [ListBeaconsActivity](https://github.com/Estimote/Android-SDK/blob/master/Demos/src/main/java/com/estimote/examples/demos/ListBeaconsActivity.java).

Comment: Thanks! I'm definitely moving along here, but now I'm having some trouble with region monitoring. Please feel free to take a look at my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28121038/android-estimote-region-monitoring. Thank you!