# Android Estimote Region Monitoring

Tags: android, estimote, region-monitoring

I am trying to add the Estimote SDK into my Android app. I'm getting pretty close, but I'm having some trouble monitoring for a region. I am following the Estimote Android SDK Guide on GitHub at https://github.com/Estimote/Android-SDK.

For some reason, the onEnteredRegion and onExitedRegion methods are not firing at all. I'm would like them to trigger any time the app sees an Estimote beacon. Thanks!

**Here is the code I have so far. Nothing too complicated:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final Region ALL_ESTIMOTE_BEACONS = new Region("regionId", "B9407F30-F5F8-466E-AFF9-25556B57FE6D", null, null);

    BeaconManager beaconManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        beaconManager = new BeaconManager(this);
        beaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(1), 0);

        beaconManager.setMonitoringListener(new MonitoringListener() {

            @Override
            public void onEnteredRegion(Region region, List<Beacon> beacons) {
                builder.setTitle("Entered Region")
                        .setMessage("")
                        .setNeutralButton("OK", null);
                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                dialog.show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onExitedRegion(Region region) {
                builder.setTitle("Exited Region")
                        .setMessage("")
                        .setNeutralButton("OK", null);
                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                dialog.show();
            }
        });
    }

    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        try {
            beaconManager.startMonitoring(ALL_ESTIMOTE_BEACONS);
        }
        catch (RemoteException e) {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting this in your `onStart()` method:

```
beaconManager.connect(new BeaconManager.ServiceReadyCallback() {
  @Override
  public void onServiceReady() {
    try {
      beaconManager.startMonitoring(region);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
      Log.d(TAG, "Error while starting monitoring");
    }
  }
```

You also need to remember about disconnecting from the BeaconManager when it's no longer needed, e.g. with this `onDestroy` implementation:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    beaconManager.disconnect();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Basically, ranging and monitoring need to be started after the beacon service is made ready, which can be easily achieved by utilizing the callback shown above.

Comment: Thanks, I'm still having an issue though. My code now won't compile and I'm getting an error that says `MainActivity has leaked ServiceConnection com.estimote.sdk.BeaconManager$InternalServiceConnection`

Comment: Right, I forgot about `beaconManager.disconnect();` in `onDestroy`. I updated my answer with a code snippet.